# Iterating through two Ilist type

Tags: c#, list, casting

consider this code

```
  public object GetDetailClasses(IList DefaultValue, IList ChangedValue)
    {
        foreach (var DefaultValueItem in DefaultValue)
        {
            foreach (var ChangedValueItem in DefaultValue)
            {
                if (ChangedValueItem.NameofProp == DefaultValueItem.NameofProp)
                { 
                //do stuff...
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

How can I iterate these two Ilist paramters for this method without casting them to related classes and compare items inside them(becuase each time they
contain data from different classes).Is there any way I can iterate these paramter and get properties inside paramter or I can use code like reflection.

Comment: It's not anonymous. `var` keyword here is not a substitution for anonymous, but rather just an `object`. Do you know about generics in C#? Have you considered them? Can you explain in more detail what you want to achieve? Can you describe what is the common behavior among different types of objects within lists?

Comment: [Generics](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/512aeb7t.aspx) and [Interfaces](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-za/library/87d83y5b.aspx) will help you here.

Comment: I know about generics and I don't want to use them.I have an list with change values and I and other one with default value.I am going to search through DefaultValue list  and change some property value to values insede ChangedValue which their property names are the same

Comment: Your only option is reflection then.

Comment: Didn't you mean for your second `foreach`: **`foreach (var ChangedValueItem in ChangedValue)`** ??

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend you to try to use generics at all cost, however if you think generics won't work for you, then reflection and beyond reflection I'd use **dynamics** so that you don't have to cast the objects like this:

```
public object GetDetailClasses(IList DefaultValue, IList ChangedValue)
{
    foreach (var DefaultValueItem in DefaultValue)
    {
        foreach (var ChangedValueItem in DefaultValue)
        {
            if (ChangedValueItem.AsDynamic().NameofProp == DefaultValueItem.AsDynamic().NameofProp)
            { 
            //do stuff...
            }
        }
    }
}
```

You'll need to reference:

https://www.nuget.org/packages/ReflectionMagic/

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution using reflection:

```
foreach (var defaultValueItem in DefaultValue)
{
    foreach (var changedValueItem in DefaultValue)
    {
        var defaultProp = defaultValueItem.GetType().GetProperties().SingleOrDefault(x => x.Name == "NameOfProp");
        var changedProp = changedValueItem.GetType().GetProperties().SingleOrDefault(x => x.Name == "NameOfProp");
        if (defaultProp == null || changedProp == null)
        {
            continue;
        }
        var defaultValue = defaultProp.GetValue(defaultValueItem);
        var changedValue = changedProp.GetValue(changedValueItem);
        if (defaultValue == changedValue)
        { 
            //do stuff...
        }
    }
}
```

Not pretty but should work.